# How to extract all tags and content between them from the XML file?

Tags: xml, bash, awk, sed

Given the XML file, I'd like to extract all strings between patterns and put in separate files, preferably with bash tools like sed, awk, grep ...

For example if I have XML file, with separator tag a:

```
<a><b>yada</b>
<c>yada</c>
</a><a>
foo</a>
<a>bar</a>
```

I'd like to have files containing:

```
<a><b>yada</b>
<c>yada</c>
</a>
```

The second one:

```
<a>
foo</a>
```

Third one:

```
<a>bar</a>
```

Comment: That is not valid XML. The `b` and `c` tags in the first `a` tag are never closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using your sample and with the assuption that there is no `</a>` inside tag a

```
sed '1!H;1h;$!d
   x
   s#\(.*</a>\).*$#\1#
   s/\(<a>.*\)$/\1/
   s/<a>/\
&/g
   s#</a>#&\
#g' YourFile \
| awk 'BEGIN        {Index=0}
       /<a>/,/<\/a>/{if ( index( $0, "<a>") > 0) Index++
                     print $0 >> "File."Index
                    }'
```

- create as many File.1 2 3 as `<a>...</a>` tag
- use the first sed to separate `<a>...</a>` substring as paragraph (not easy for me in same awk as output action part), using the awk to send to different file (not possible from sed)
- the remove of heading and trailing part of file are optionnal `s#\(.*</a>\).*$#\1#` and `s/\(<a>.*\)$/\1/`

Comment: I've ended up using this solution, because XML is not well formatted in my case. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use Python, which has an XML parser in its standard library. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import xml.dom.minidom as DOM;
import sys;

# first parameter is input file
dom = DOM.parse(sys.argv[1])
i = 0

# find, iterate through all 'a' tags
for tag in dom.getElementsByTagName('a'):
    # Using filenames output1.xml, output2.xml etc.
    # Change format string as required.
    i = i + 1
    with open('output{}.xml'.format(i), 'w') as f:
        print >> f, tag.toxml()
```

Save as `foo.py`, call

```
python foo.py input.xml
```

(or `./foo.py input.xml` after `chmod +x`)